# Regex to get each section

Tags: python, regex, ansible

Below is the content:

`router eigrp 1
  redistribute ospf 14 route-map test2
  redistribute static
  vrf Automation
    autonomous-system 52
    exec-timeout 5
    default
router ospf 14
  router-id 1.1.1.1
  area 0.0.0.25 nssa
  redistribute static route-map test1
  redistribute eigrp 10 route-map test2
  area 0.0.0.0 range 10.10.10.0/24
  area 0.0.0.0 authentication message-digest
  area 0.0.0.25 authentication message-digest
  log-adjacency-changes
  maximum-paths 8
  auto-cost reference-bandwidth 10 Gbps`

Need help with regex to capture first section of eigrp starting with router eigrp and capturing anything indented by either 2 space or 4 spaces. Same thing for second section starting with router ospf. greedy=yes. Thank you!

Comment: What is the language/tool?

Comment: ansible and python

Comment: The following pattern works in C#: `string pattern = @"router eigrp 1\r((\s{4}|\s{2}).+?\r)+";`

Comment: When I put this into https://regex101.com/ didn't work.

Comment: keep it simple, just filter on lines with a space: `grep '^\s'`

Comment: What about [`^router (?:.*)(?:\n  .*)*`](https://regex101.com/r/d2kXyZ/1) with "m" ([multiline](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE)) flag?

Comment: Almost there just don't know to get rid of that group 1 match. don't need a group. https://regex101.com/r/GamGxt/1

Comment: @trincot thank you that worked!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following regex combined with the [multiline](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) flag:

[`^router (?:.*)(?:\n .*)*`](https://regex101.com/r/d2kXyZ/1)